# Is it valid for HowTO schema have description property?

Tags: seo, google, schema.org

This is a `HowTo schema` I copied from [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/how-to#visual).

```
{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "HowTo",
      "name": "How to tile a kitchen backsplash",
      "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "height": "406",
        "width": "305"
      },
      -----
}
```

I can not find if it is valid to use a `description` property like the `name` it has. Will Google display the `description` property?

```
{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "HowTo",
      "name": "How to tile a kitchen backsplash",
      "description": "5 steps to tile a kitchen backsplash",
       "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "height": "406",
        "width": "305"
      },
      -----
}
```

https://search.google.com/test/rich-results does not complain. However, It does not complain either if I use a random property, eg.:

```
{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "HowTo",
      "name": "How to tile a kitchen backsplash",
      "example": "5 steps to tile a kitchen backsplash",
       "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "height": "406",
        "width": "305"
      },
      -----
}
```

Comment: If Google docs don't specifically mention supporting description, it is unlikely they will use it in the rich snippets. But there is no harm in including properties that schema.org supports.